# How to fix a folder that is connected to git by mistake?

Tags: github

I am new to Github.

So I have this a working folder Documents/Projects containing all my projects folder.

Each folder inside has its own repository on Github.

But I think a friend of mine, while helping me to set up a project folder, he ran git init on the Documents/Projects (not inside the project folder), resulting this showed up on my terminal:

```
Lalas-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects (master *+)$
```

How do I fix this? Does it mean it got synced to a git repo?
It was supposed to be like this:

```
Lalas-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects$
```

I am a beginner in Github. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check if there is a **.git** folder inside your 

Lalas-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects

```
ls -la ~/Documents/Projects
```

and if it exists, you can delete it by

```
rm -r ~/Documents/Projects/.git
```

**.git** folder means that your directory is under a version control and if a new repo was accidentally created there, removing it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command `git config --get remote.origin.url` you can see if the directory has been linked to an actual repository.  If `git init` was ran by itself, it will not have a remote origin.

If it has been linked, then you should run `git log` to see what commits were last made, and then you'll know if your friend added and committed all your projects to their repository (accidentally or on purpose).

If they have, then you can ask them to remove the files (technically you could do it with git, but you should let them do it in case you break something of theirs).

Once that's all sorted, you'll need to remove the `.git` folder from your main project directory, as that contains the git information.